# Animating point

Tags: graphics, animation

I'm new to mathematica and can't seem to make this animation work. Any help?

```
g = 9.81; 
x[t_] := x0 + vel*Cos[th]*t;
y[t_] := y0 + vel*Sin[th]*t - (g*t^2)/2;
vel = 0; x0 = 5; y0 = 100; th = 0;
Animate[
Graphics[
{PointSize -> 0.05, Point[{x[t], y[t]}]}] , {t, 0, 10}]
```

the animation is starting without error but it's just a non-moving point.

(maybe has something to do with the version of mathematica I'm using? it's v7.0 trial version)

Comment: `PlotRange` needs to be an option to `Graphics` inside `Animate`  ( Your `Graphics` line does nothing at all, `Graphics` does not "remember" options from prior calls )

Comment: Thanks, but that's not the issue. all it displays is a non-moving point in the midle of the screen.

Comment: It does not move because by default `Graphics` auto ranges every frame to center the point. Thats why you need to specify a fixed plot range.

Comment: It can also be useful to draw a box to give yourself a reference frame, try this : `Graphics[{{FaceForm[None], EdgeForm[Black],  Rectangle[{0, 0}, {200, 200}]}, PointSize -> 0.05,  Point[{x[t], y[t]}]}]`

Comment: You're a genius, thanks! it seemed to work in another version so I tried this again here. (the general graphics options) case solved

Answer (score 2):

```
g = 9.81;
x[t_] := x0 + vel*Cos[th]*t;
y[t_] := y0 + vel*Sin[th]*t - (g*t^2)/2;
vel = 0;
x0 = 5;
y0 = 100;
th = 0;

{xmin, xmax} = #[{x[t], 0 <= t <= 10}, t] & /@
  {MinValue, MaxValue}

(*  {5, 5}  *)

{ymin, ymax} = #[{y[t], 0 <= t <= 10}, t] & /@
  {MinValue, MaxValue}

(*  {-390.5, 100.}  *)

Animate[
 Graphics[{
   PointSize -> 0.05,
   Point[{x[t], y[t]}]},
  PlotRange -> {
    {Floor[xmin - 5, 10], Ceiling[xmax + 5, 10]},
    {Floor[ymin - 5, 10], Ceiling[ymax + 5, 10]}},
  Frame -> True,
  AspectRatio -> 1], {t, 0, 10}]
```